# How to change headers in Gmail when "sending as" from another account?

Tags: gmail

I am using Gmail (on web [browser] and android clients).
I am sending messages from my Gmail, using the "send as" feature: that is, I use send as from my organization/work ("Use Gmail to send from your other email addresses").
This organization adds a disclaimer to all outgoing emails. The organization's email server is MS Outlook.
Even when I send messages from Gmail, using "send as" my organization's email address, *the disclaimer is added* to all my outgoing emails.

Is there a way in Gmail to remove this disclaimer?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail, as an end-user email client, can't remove the disclaimer because it's added by your organization "MS Outlook" server after the email leaves the email client but before delivering it to the recipient server.

Comment: Thanks Ruben. Are you totally positive about this? Because other (non-web) clients *can* remove the disclaimer, as I've seen. So I wonder what is the difference here between gmail and other clients, both using the same email address.